# Issue with rspec and faiing tests and clearing local storage

Tags: rspec, capybara

I am testing an application that uses local storage for user data. After my scenarios I clear local storage using the command 'page.execute_script("window.localStorage.clear()"). This is so that for the next scenario the state of the application is in a clean state and does not have any user data left over from the previous test.

This works fine when the tests are all passing and the last step is reached which is the clear local storage step. However if my test fails at some point during the test then this command is not executed(as its the last step) and this is causing problems with the next scenario as there remains data stored from the previous failed scenario.

I have tried using putting the clear local storage command in an after all block but this did not work for me.

Anybody else have any problems like this and how did you deal with it? Is there a way I can say if a test fails, then clear cookies, local storage etc?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `after :each`?

Comment: Hey Dave - After each would not work for me as I test an entire page at time, and as such do not want to reset sessions or clear local storage after each it block.